# SLURM job. NameError: name 'python3' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, cron, hpc, slurm, nameerror

For a while now I've been trying to figure out how to run a job on slurm.

Python versions in the user directory:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.5
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.8
```

test.py includes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
true = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv")
print('Just Testing. End for now.')
```

gpu.job that is passed to SLURM:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#SBATCH --job-name=testjob       # Job name
#SBATCH --output=job.%j.out      # Name of output file (%j expands to jobId)
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4        # Schedule one core
#SBATCH --gres=gpu               # Schedule a GPU
#SBATCH --time=71:59:59          # Run time (hh:mm:ss) - run for one hour max
#SBATCH --partition=red          # Run on either the Red or Brown queue
#SBATCH --mail-type=END          # Send an email when the job finishes
#SBATCH --export=ALL             # All of the users environment will be loaded from callers environment


python3 /home/username/test/test.py
```

After running `sbatch gpu.job` , I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/var/spool/slurm/d/job402350/slurm_script", line 13, in
>
> python3 /home/username/test/test.py
>
> NameError: name 'python3' is not defined ~

These variations also did not help and gives the same error:

```
python3 test.py
/usr/bin/python3 test.py
/usr/bin/python3 /home/username/test/test.py
```

An advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to run python3 inside python3? Usually when you do `#!/usr/bin/python3` it already knows about the python scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your submission script is a shell script, not a Python script. So the first line of your submission script should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

rather than

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Technically, you can submit a job script that is a Python script, but then the `#SBATCH` directives got directly in the Python script and that is the script you submit:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#SBATCH --job-name=testjob       # Job name
#SBATCH --output=job.%j.out      # Name of output file (%j expands to jobId)
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4        # Schedule one core
#SBATCH --gres=gpu               # Schedule a GPU
#SBATCH --time=71:59:59          # Run time (hh:mm:ss) - run for one hour max
#SBATCH --partition=red          # Run on either the Red or Brown queue
#SBATCH --mail-type=END          # Send an email when the job finishes
#SBATCH --export=ALL             # All of the users environment will be loaded from callers environment


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
true = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv")
print('Just Testing. End for now.')
```

Then you can `sbatch` this Python script directly. But most often, using a Bash script is preferred to be able to setup the environment, change directories, copy files back and forth, etc. which is easier in Bash than in Python.